How to setup input and output txt file in vs code for c programming in mac os?
Cant setup input and output txt file for vs code in mac os. How to configure setting.json for the viable output?
I tried using setting.json config for windows but doesn’t help. Tried asking to chatgpt and copilot. Still does not work. What is the right method? What am I doing wrong?

Are you asking for how to open files from the program, or how to pass file names from the command line? Or both?
